# Firefox asks for username/password on every HTTP request with Digest Authentication enabled on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, firefox, iis-6, digest-authentication

I've recently enabled Digest Authentication on an intranet website/application I am creating for my company in ASP.NET.

The reason I have done so is because Windows Authentication seemed to only work for some users, and not for others. I could not figure out why nor do I know enough about IIS to try and trace the issue. After some trial and error, I found that digest authentication seemed to give me the behaviour that I wanted. That is: allow only users with a valid account on the domain to log in to the website with their credentials.

The problem now, is that Firefox (3+) seems to ask for the user to authenticate on every HTTP request sent to the server. This does not appear to occur in Internet Explorer (6+) or Chrome.

I've tried searching for solutions but I always arrive at dead-ends. I'll find a discussion about the issue, and every posted solution leads to a dead link...or it's on Experts Exchange and I don't have access to view to solution.

The issue appears to be related (from what I've read) to the way the different browsers send their authentication headers vs how IIS interprets them. I'm not sure what I can do to change this though? One of the solutions I had found mentioned writing an ISAPI filter to fix this, but of course the link to the finished filter was broken and I have no idea how to go about making one myself.

I've tried messing with the NTLM and other auth related strings in about:config to try and force Firefox to trust my server but that doesn't seem to work either.

From a few other sources I've read, it appears that everything *should* work if I switch back to Windows Authentication, but then I'm back at square one where the authentication would work only for some users and not others.

A solution for either problem would work for me, but I have very little information for the Windows Authentication issue. If someone could guide me through tracing the problem I'd gladly post more information for it as well.

---

Here are the URLs I've found discussing what seems like the same problem. (Sorry I couldn't make them all links, it wouldn't let me post otherwise)

- support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=pt-BR&forumId=1&comments_parentId=346851
- www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/Web_Browsers/Mozilla/Q_24427378.html
- channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/168006-Twin-bugs-in-IIS-IE-unfair-competitive-advantage-EDIT-SOLVED/
- www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.inetserver.iis.security/2006-03/msg00141.html

Comment: what does network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris in about:config look like?

Comment: It's a blank string at the moment. I've tried adding my server address to it but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 9):

This is a know bug in FF. [See Advanced digest authentication works from Internet Explorer however we receive multiple authentication prompts on each GET request from fire fox](http://blogs.iis.net/sakyad/archive/2009/04/04/advanced-digest-authentication-works-from-internet-explorer-however-we-receive-multiple-authentication-prompts-on-each-get-request-from-fire-fox.aspx)

IE 6  had the same bug.A potential workaround would be to re-enable "old" Digest in IIS6:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d6e22ac-0215-4d12-81e9-c9262c91b797.mspx?mfr=true

Currently, if the server send an opaque directive, the IE client will return this directive value as specified in the RFC. Unfortunately, for follow-on requests from the client where the nonce count is incremented (count 2 and beyond) the opaque directive value is not sent. This then fails authentication on the server and a 401 Unauthorized is returned. The IE client now requests the username and password for the new challenge and the file is retrieved.

This requires an additional round trip and the user is prompted for credential each time.

The RFC states that the opaque must always be sent on requests from the client.
The Digest implementation that IE6 is using is not RFC compliant (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt).
3.2.2 The Authorization Request Header
   The values of the opaque and algorithm fields must be those supplied
   in the WWW-Authenticate response header for the entity being
   requested.

3.3 Digest Operation
   A client should remember the username, password, nonce, nonce count and
   opaque values associated with an authentication session to use to
   construct the Authorization header in future requests within that
   protection space.

Because the client is required to return the value of the opaque
   directive given to it by the server for the duration of a session,
   the opaque data may be used to transport authentication session state
   information.
-------- Edit addition -----

> > Windows Authentication seemed to only work for some users, and not for others.
> >     How did it fail? Did you enable impersonation?

Comment: Finally an explanation! Unfortunately, the links you put for the potential work-around are broken :( Would you happen to have the working links?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-us/?query=digest+authentication+%22IIS+6%22 might get you started. I'll try to find the exact article next week.

Comment: For your edit: Windows authentication allowed some users to log in, and for others it would deny access entirely. I couldn't figure out what the difference between the ones whom it worked for, and for those who didn't was; it seemed to be entirely random. *edit* And also, as I've mentioned I don't really know much about IIS...thus don't know what Impersonation is. I will look into it though.